# Reduce Number of Variables in ggplot Legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the below data frame in R:

```
       eta      x.1   x.2 x.3     y.1     y.2   y.3    xz.1    xz.2  xz.3
eta.0    1 28.00000 28.00000 28.00000 -1.0000000 -1.0000000 -1.0000000 -1.0000000 -1.0000000 -1.0000000
eta.01   2 27.99999 27.99999 27.99995 -0.9999824 -0.9999824 -0.9999555 -0.9999999 -0.9999999 -0.9999988
eta.1    3 27.98915 28.00041 27.99914 -0.9948991 -0.9996051 -0.9987214 -0.9996547 -1.0000389 -1.0000022
eta.5    4 25.57216 27.98243 27.98737  0.0000000 -0.9922089 -0.9954901 -0.8380154 -0.9995550 -0.9996936
eta.10   5 25.38172 25.94990 28.04486  0.0000000  0.0000000 -1.0172488 -0.8670870 -0.9492688 -1.0004286
```

I've used `gather` to construct a new data frame and want to plot each variable. I'm now trying to plot all of the variables, however, I want to plot them corresponding to the second number together. So I want to plot `x.1`, `y.1`, and `xz.1` together and create a legend that only has three variables, say `Model 1`, `Model 2`, `Model 3` in `ggplot`.

```
library(tidyverse)
# Gather dataframe
df.gather <- gather(df, "variables", "value", 2:ncol(df))

shapes <- rep(c(15,16,17),3)
colours <- c("#c97a76","#5abd47","#3160e1")
names <- c("Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3")

ggplot <- ggplot(df.gather, aes(x = eta, y = value, col=variables, group = variables, shape = variables))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(show.legend = F)+
  expand_limits(y=30)+
  scale_shape_manual(values = shapes, guide = F)+
  ylab("Point Estimate")+
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
      axis.ticks.length = unit(.25,"cm"),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_blank(),
      legend.key = element_blank(),
      legend.box.background = element_rect(color="black", size=0.5))+
  scale_color_manual(values =  c(rep(colours,3)), guide = F)
```

I currently have the below plot but was trying to figure out if it was possible to merge each model into 1 and only have "Model 1", "Model 2", and "Model 3" in the legend corresponding to shape and colour.

Thanks in advance.

[image: text]

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure why the initial question had `[![names <- c("Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3")][1]][1]`, but `ncol(df)` should work for the initial data.

Comment: It's OK; your edits made everything clearer. To clarify one more thing: `df.gather$variables` has values like `x.1`, `xz.2`, etc.; the `Model` number is given after the dots, right?

Comment: Yes, the model number is after the dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it: Make a new variable giving the `Model`, then use that for shape and color:

```r
df.gather$Model <- gsub("[a-z.]+", "", df.gather$variables)
ggplot(data = df.gather, mapping = aes(x = eta, y = value, group = variables,
                                       color = Model, shape = Model)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    expand_limits(y=30) +
    ylab("Point Estimate")
```

[image]